# Nosetests - Guess The Number Game

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nosetests

I am trying to write a few tests for a random input number game but not too sure how to proceed on.

I am following the Python Game from http://inventwithpython.com/chapter4.html

Started the tests with a file test_guess.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
import pexpect as pe

import guess as g

class GuessTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.intro = 'I have chosen a number from 1-10'
        self.request = 'Guess a number: '
        self.responseHigh = "That's too high."
        self.responseLow  = "That's too low."
        self.responseCorrect = "That's right!"
        self.goodbye = 'Goodbye and thanks for playing!'

    def test_main(self):
        #cannot execute main now because it will
        #require user input
        from guess import main

    def test_guessing_hi_low_4(self):
        # Conversation assuming number is 4
        child = pe.spawn('python guess.py')
        child.expect(self.intro,timeout=5)
        child.expect(self.request,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('5')
        child.expect(self.responseHigh,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('3')
        child.expect(self.responseLow,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('4')
        child.expect(self.responseCorrect,timeout=5)
        child.expect(self.goodbye,timeout=5)

    def test_guessing_low_hi_4(self):
        # Conversation assuming number is 4
        child = pe.spawn('python guess.py')
        child.expect(self.intro,timeout=5)
        child.expect(self.request,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('3')
        child.expect(self.responseLow,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('5')
        child.expect(self.responseHigh,timeout=5)
        child.sendline('4')
        child.expect(self.responseCorrect,timeout=5)
        child.expect(self.goodbye,timeout=5)
```

and the guess.py file with

```
intro = 'I have chosen a number from 1-10'
request = 'Guess a number: '
responseHigh = "That's too high."
responseLow  = "That's too low."
responseCorrect = "That's right!"
goodbye = 'Goodbye and thanks for playing!'


def main():
    print(intro)
    user_input = raw_input(request)
    print(responseHigh)
    print(request)
    user_input = raw_input(request)
    print(responseLow)
    user_input = raw_input(request)
    print(responseCorrect)
    print(goodbye)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Not sure How to proceed on with writing a few more tests with if statement to test if the value is low or high. I was told to try a command line switch like optparse to pass the number but not sure how to do that either.

Somewhat of a new person with Python, any guidance or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do command line parsing in nosetests, you'll have to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334635/how-to-access-plugin-options-within-a-test-python-nose) (at least that's what I had to do), i.e. create a plugin that will give you access to the command line parameter in nosetests.  Once you had the plugin added which gave you the command line parameter, it would be pretty easy to create a test that would take advantage of that passed in parameter.

```
from test_args import case_options

class GuessTest(TestCase):
...

    def test_guessing(self):
        # Conversation assuming number is 4
        if case_options.number < 4:
            # Do something
        elif case_option.number > 4:
            # Do some other test
        else: 
            # Do the final test
```

Does that make sense?  I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do so if I am, just let me know and hopefully we can clear it up.