# Accessing data defined by a plugin from various test files

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I'm trying to implement a set of nose tests running form within my python code.

I'm calling nose    `run` method from this file, adding it a custom plugin based on an [example from the nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_init_plugin/init_plugin.html):

```
import os
import sys
import outer_packages
import nose
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import misc_methods
from rednose import RedNose
import termstyle

class CTRexScenario():
    configuration = None
    trex          = None
    platform      = None

class CTRexTestConfiguringPlugin(Plugin):
    def options(self, parser, env={}):
        parser.add_option('--trex-scenario-config', action='store',
                            dest='config_path', default='config/config.yaml',
                            help='Specify path to the T-Rex testing scenario, defining T-Rex, platform and a TFTP server. Default is /config/config.yaml')

    def configure(self, options, conf):
        if options.config_path:
            self.configuration = misc_methods.load_complete_config_file(options.config_path)
            self.enabled = True

    def begin (self):
        CTRexScenario.configuration = self.configuration

def set_report_dir (report_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(report_dir):
        os.mkdir(report_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # setting defaults. By default we run all the test suite
    specific_tests   = False;
    long_test       = False
    report_dir      = "reports"

    for arg in sys.argv:
        if 'unit_tests/' in arg:
            specific_tests = True;

    nose_argv= sys.argv + ['-s','-v','--exe', '--rednose', '--with-xunit','--xunit-file=' + report_dir + "/unit_test.xml"]

    # Run all of the unit tests or just the selected ones
    if not specific_tests:
        nose_argv += ['unit_tests']

    result = nose.run(argv = nose_argv, addplugins = [RedNose(), CTRexTestConfiguringPlugin()])#, plugins=[CConfiguringPlugin()])

    if result == True:
        print termstyle.green("passed!")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(-1);
```

Now, I want do create a general test case, from which, containing this Scenario such that there will be a same shared scenario for all of the following tests. i.e.- All tests inheriting from the general case will base on the very same `setUp` and `tearDown` methods.

Here's the general test file:

```
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import trex
import misc_methods
import sys

class CTRexGeneral_Test():
    """This class defines the general testcase of the T-Rex traffic generator"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = CTRexScenario()
        ##### Here I want to config the rest of the scenario, based on the passed configuration file

    def test_can_frobnicate(self):
        assert (self.a.configuration==None)
        # assert 2*5==10

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

**Unfortunately, I don't understand how should I access the fetched configuration (which parsed already by the Plugin) from the general test file**

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access plugin options within a test? (Python Nose)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334635/how-to-access-plugin-options-within-a-test-python-nose)

Comment: @Oleksiy, The thing is, that based on the configure file I am trying to create a setup procedure that takes some time (hardware fixed time). This should only happen once in the entire test suite, and once it is done, a need the access to each one of the CTRexScenario attributes (configuration, platform, etc) from each of the test files, as further manipulation might have to be done and this is the link to those hardware appliances. I'm not sure that the provided link is the case (tried the global stuff, didn't provide what I wanted)